# how to update a list of checkbox data into a pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am working on a registration booking program.

I have a Form with a list of checkboxes that need to be updated to reflect if an attendee is booked for an event.

**Veiw**

```
       @foreach($programs as $program)
            <tr>
            @foreach( Auth::user()->attendee as $attendee )
                <td>
                {{
                    Form::checkbox(
                        'attendee[]',
                        array($attendee->id=>$program->id), //ERROR: will not accept array :(
                        ($attendee->scheduled_programs->contains($program))
                    )
                }}
                </td>
            @endforeach
            //irrelevant table data
       @endforeach
```

How do I get the attendee_id and program_id to to my controller to update the pivot table with?

Answer (score 1):

This allowed me to send both indexes as an array.
**Veiw**

```
       @foreach($programs as $program)
            <tr>
            @foreach( Auth::user()->attendee as $attendee )
                <td>
                {{
                    Form::checkbox(
                        'prog_booking['. $attendee->id .'][]',
                        $program->id
                        ($attendee->scheduled_programs->contains($program))
                    )
                }}
                </td>
            @endforeach
            //irrelevant table data
       @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

With a checkbox you have to check if the value exists. If it does, it means the checkbox is checked.

```
$chk = Input::has('name.0.name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra data by adding a second param to the attach function. You'll need:

```
$attendee->program()->attach($attendee, array('program_id', $program_id);
```